# How to move a sprite across the screen back-and-forth

Tags: c++, ios, animation, cocos2d-x

This is a 2d game, which contains moving platforms that are spawned randomly along the X axis. I need to move them across the screen horizontally, but when they hit the edge, they will move in opposite direction. And, to make the game less predictable, I would like to start moving the sprite in the direction that is far away of the edge.

How can I accomplish this effect in Cocos2d-x C++ ?

**EDIT:** So far, this is the code that I am testing, but with one major issue, it works only for the first platform. When a new platform is placed in, for some reason it go out of the screen and I won't see it again. I am pretty sure that there is a better way to do it, so, thanks in advance for your help.

Be aware that this code is inside of the Delta function:

```
void GameScene::step(float dt) {
...
```

**CODE:**

```
for (int p = kPlatformsStartTag; p < kPlatformsStartTag + kNumPlatforms; p++) {
        CCSprite *plat = (CCSprite*)getChildByTag(p);
        CCPoint pos = plat->getPosition();
        CCSize size = plat->getContentSize();

        if(plat->getTag() == kMovingPlatformTag)  {

            if(pos.x > CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width - (size.width /2)  || !isMovingToLeft) {
                pos.x -= 0.7f  * plat->getScaleX();
                isMovingToLeft = (pos.x <= size.width /2  ) ? true : false; //(pos.x <= size.width ) ? true : false;

                //Not allow to move the platform beyond the left edge of the screen
                if(pos.x < 0) {
                    pos.x = size.width /2;
                    isMovingToLeft = true; //Here we force to flip the movement to the opposite direction
                }
                CCLog("1. value of isMovingToLeft : %d", isMovingToLeft);

            }

            if (pos.x >= 0 && isMovingToLeft) { //size.width could be greater that 20 pixels margin
                pos.x += 0.7f  * plat->getScaleX();
                isMovingToLeft = (pos.x >= CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width - (size.width /2) ) ? false : true;

                //Not allow to move the platform beyond the right edge of the screen
                if(pos.x > CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width) {
                    pos.x = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width  - (size.width /2);
                    isMovingToLeft = false; //Here we force to flip the movement to the opposite direction.

                }
                CCLog("2. value of isMovingToLeft : %d", isMovingToLeft);
            }
//            CCLog("value of pos.x => %f", pos.x);
            plat->setPosition(pos);
        }

    }
```

Comment: have you used physics in your game ? are you using your platforms as bodies or simple sprites?

Comment: Please, check my last update. I have posted the code that I am testing. Thanks so much.

Comment: i just go through your this pasted code but i am not getting much idea on what you exactly want to do ... it would be nice if you could explain more in to this.

Comment: I have a set of platforms, that are spawned randomly along the X axis, but only few of them are "Moving Platforms". So, first I search for those with the kMovingPlatformTag tag, and the I decide if it will move to the LEFT or RIGHT. The effect is a movement across the screen back-and-forth. Once the platform touches the edge, it should move back to the other edge of the screen. The problem, I am having now, is when the screen scrolls up, the other "Moving Platforms" get out of screen edge (they continue moving and then they disappear).